# First tensorflow tutorial doesn't work with different training data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I've recently installed tensorflow on my computer, but I'm confused about some results I'm getting from the first tutorial program. It's a very simple linear regression model that finds W and b for W*x + b = y:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W*x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# training data
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
for i in range(1000):
  sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})

# evaluate training accuracy
curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
```

result:

```
W: [-0.9999969] b: [ 0.99999082] loss: 5.69997e-11
```

It works!

But then I changed the training data from:

```
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3]
```

to:

```
x_train = [145, 146, 147, 148]
y_train = [151, 152, 153, 154]
```

I should theoretically get W: [~1] b: [~6] loss: ~0, but instead I get:

```
W: [ nan] b: [ nan] loss: nan
```

Below is a print of i, W, b, and loss after 10 iterations of training

```
[0, '0.3', '-0.3', '4.74e+04']  
[1, '1276', '8.408', '1.396e+11']  
[2, '-2.188e+06', '-1.494e+04', '4.111e+17']  
[3, '3.755e+09', '2.563e+07', '1.211e+24']  
[4, '-6.445e+12', '-4.399e+10', '3.566e+30']  
[5, '1.106e+16', '7.549e+13', '1.05e+37']  
[6, '-1.898e+19', '-1.296e+17', 'inf']  
[7, '3.257e+22', '2.223e+20', 'inf']  
[8, '-5.59e+25', '-3.816e+23', 'inf']  
[9, '9.594e+28', '6.548e+26', 'inf']
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I'm using Tensorflow 1.4.0 (CPU only) with Python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

EDIT: normalizing the data helped, thanks!

Comment: Try playing with the learning rate. Alternatively, I have a feeling the gradients are exploding and the bias isn't able to compensate for the very large unnormalized inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Turn down your learning rate
2. normalize your train data like (x-mean)/std.

I recommend second.You can have a try.